# Why mysqli_connect doesn't respect MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, timeout

The code below will stuck on `real_connect()` 100%. `set_time_limit` and `default_socket_timeout` and `MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` have been set, but not working.

I tested on PHP 5.6 and PHP 7.1. mysql driver is mysqlnd.

```
set_time_limit(30);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 10);
$mysql = new mysqli();
$mysql->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5);
$mysql->real_connect('www.baidu.com', 'root', 'xxx', 'xxx', 80);
```

Questions:

1. Why PHP process stuck on `real_connect` when using host address `www.baidu.com` and port number `80`?
2. Why `MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` and the other timeout settings are not working?
3. For this particular situation, is there any way to set a timeout that can work?

Comment: Well, mysql runs on port 3306 not 80.

Comment: @AlexBarker I know that. I just want to know why PHP stuck on real_connect when using host address "www.baidu.com" and port number "80", although I have set timeout

Comment: Set `MYSQLI_OPT_READ_TIMEOUT` also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two timeout settings. One is [`MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_connect_timeout) and the other one is [`MYSQLI_OPT_READ_TIMEOUT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_read_timeout). The second one is poorly documented, but this option can be set in two ways.

Using `mysqli::set_opt`:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli();
$mysqli->set_opt(MYSQLI_OPT_READ_TIMEOUT, 3); // 3 seconds
$mysqli->connect('example.com', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset
```

or using the INI confiuguration setting. Set this in php.ini file:

```
mysqlnd.net_read_timeout =  3
```

The ini setting is just a default value for `MYSQLI_OPT_READ_TIMEOUT` if one is not provided through `mysqli::set_opt`, so whichever way you chose will work.

Comment: I searched the source code of PHP on github.Found that `MYSQLI_OPT_READ_TIMEOUT` was added since of version 7.2.If you use this constant before version 7.2, a Notice error will be reported

Comment: @ljfrocky Thanks, for pointing it out. The docs are now updated.

Comment: If PHP version < 7.2. then, according to the following reference, `if (!defined('MYSQLI_OPT_READ_TIMEOUT')) {define ('MYSQLI_OPT_READ_TIMEOUT', 3);}` may be a workaround https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php#122965

Comment: @arya This won't make it work though.

Answer (score 3):

I found the reason. The timeout in my case is a read timeout, not a connection timeout. Therefore `MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` is not working. The solution is to set  `mysqlnd.net_read_timeout` in the `php.ini` file. The parameter value is in seconds.Such as:
`mysqlnd.net_read_timeout = 3`